# Switch nodes - javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to loop over DOM-elements with `querySelectorAll`but i cannot get my script to work.

Answer:

```
x = document.querySelectorAll('.product-promo-price p');
y = document.querySelectorAll(".product-current-price");
for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++){ 
  var temp = y[i].innerText; // hold value you are going to overwrite
  y[i].innerText=x[i].innerText;  // overwrite it
  x[i].innerText = temp  // use the temp variable to set x
}
```

problem is that x is overwritten in for loop. I change the order it is same effect.

**Scenario:**
There is 2 DOM nodes (`.product-promo-price p` and `.product-current-price`)
I need to switch the content on these two DOM-nodes.

```
<div class="caption">
  <div class="product-color">
    <span style="background-color: #000000; " data-product-id="7272"></span>
    <span style="background-color: #0099FF; " data-product-id="7273"></span>
  </div>
  <h4 class="product-brand">Huawei</h4>
  <h3 class="product-title" title="Mate 20 Lite">Mate 20 Lite</h3>
  <h4 class="product-promo-subscription">m/ 12,  mnd avtale</h4>
  <div class="main-price">
    <p class="product-current-price">3.290,-</p>
  </div>
  <p class="price-mode-label"></p>
  <div class="product-promo-price">
    <p>3.290,-</p>
  </div>
  <div class="total-price">
    <p>Minste totalpris første 12 mnd - fra: 5.678,-</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `x` *is* defined inside your loop. What makes you think it isn't? Would also help to show us your HTML.

Comment: If you don't have the same number of elements for both promo-price and current-price you'll always have an error thrown

Comment: x is defined with y so if x can not be referenced, than why would y?

Comment: There is always the same numbers (length)

Comment: How can i switch the innerText between X and Y. Now only one get switched

Comment: once you switch one, than not sure how you expect to switch it back since you just overwrote it.

Comment: x = [1,1,1] and y = [2,2,2]. After first loop you have x=[1,1,1] and y=[1,1,1] and you want to know why you do not get [2,2,2] back?

Comment: I was trying to explain WHY it is not working. Solution, swap them in one loop with a temporary variable.

Comment: Thank you @epascarello for explaining why it does not work.

Comment: You should do this on the server side and not with JS. Someone could read the currentPrize and think it IS the current prize, but in fact it is the promo prize. From a legal point of view this could be dangerous. And what about the users without JS?

Comment: This is used for A/B testing @HerrSerker. If Javascript is disabled then no worries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You overwrite an array and than you try to use that overwritten array to put values back into the other one. It is hard to do that when you already changed the values.

Do it in one loop not two. Use a temp variable to hold the value you will overwrite.

```
for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++){ 
  var temp = y[i].innerText; // hold value you are going to overwrite
  y[i].innerText=x[i].innerText;  // overwrite it
  x[i].innerText = temp  // use the temp variable to set x
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one `.caption` element with prizes and there is only the slight chance that one of them doesn't have a current prize or a promo prize, then you would be in big trouble. You would seemingly randomly switch prizes between smart phones.

So it would be better to loop over every `.caption` and swap the prizes for every caption

```js
console.clear();

var captions = document.querySelectorAll('.caption')
for(var i = 0; i < captions.length; i++) {
  let caption = captions[i];
  let promoPrice = caption.querySelector('.product-promo-price p');
  let currentPrice = caption.querySelector('.product-current-price');
  
  let temp = promoPrice.textContent;
  promoPrice.textContent = currentPrice.textContent;
  currentPrice.textContent = temp;  
}
```

```html
<div class="caption">
  <div class="product-color">
    <span style="background-color: #000000; " data-product-id="7272"></span>
    <span style="background-color: #0099FF; " data-product-id="7273"></span>
  </div>
  <h4 class="product-brand">Huawei</h4>
  <h3 class="product-title" title="Mate 20 Lite">Mate 20 Lite</h3>
  <h4 class="product-promo-subscription">m/ 12,  mnd avtale</h4>
  <div class="main-price">
    <p class="product-current-price">3.490,- C</p>
  </div>
  <p class="price-mode-label"></p>
  <div class="product-promo-price">
    <p>3.290,- P</p>
  </div>
  <div class="total-price">
    <p>Minste totalpris første 12 mnd - fra: 5.678,-</p>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="caption">
  <div class="product-color">
    <span style="background-color: #000000; " data-product-id="7272"></span>
    <span style="background-color: #0099FF; " data-product-id="7273"></span>
  </div>
  <h4 class="product-brand">Huawei</h4>
  <h3 class="product-title" title="Mate 20 Lite">Mate 10 Pro</h3>
  <h4 class="product-promo-subscription">m/ 24</h4>
  <div class="main-price">
    <p class="product-current-price">4.390,- C</p>
  </div>
  <p class="price-mode-label"></p>
  <div class="product-promo-price">
    <p>12.290,- P</p>
  </div>
  <div class="total-price">
    <p>Minste totalpris første 12 mnd - fra: 5.678,-</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

the DOM that you are showing does not contain ".product-current-price" or ".product-promo-price p" for that reason no X and Y are not defined.

Greetings.

Comment: What are you talking about